# регистрация нажатия эмодзи

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

Как сделать, чтобы бот отслеживал нажатие реакции под эмбедом вызванным командой,
как на этой картинке?

[image: по этому примеру]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда при помощи команды создается сообщение с эмбедом, сохраняем его id в какую-либо переменную:

```
msgid = None

@bot.command()
async def create_embed(ctx):
    global msgid                        # работает с глобальной переменной, так как доступ к ней нужен из разных функций
    embed =                             # здесь создаем embed
    msg = await ctx.send(embed = embed) # при отправке сообщения создаем его же объект
    msgid = msg.id                      # записываем id сообщения в переменную
```

После чего используем событие  [`on_raw_reaction_add(payload)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_raw#discord.on_raw_reaction_add) для работы с объектом, к которому была добавлена реакция.

Проверяем, чтобы эта реакция была не от бота. А также чтобы id сообщения с новой реакцией совпадал с `msgid`.

**При необходимости считывания нескольких сообщений, можно записывать не переменную `msgid`, а список (`list`)**

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    global msgid
    if (payload.user_id != bot.user.id) and (payload.message_id == msgid):
        print('Нажата реакция перед сообщением', payload.message_id)
```